# Указание конкретного ip-адреса сокетам в Java.net

Tags: java, сокет, клиент-сервер, ip

Требуется создать простейшее клиент-серверное приложение. Использую библиотеку java.net. Каким образом возможно привязать сокеты сервера и клиента к конкретным ip-адресов?

Comment: Это как? Что значит "привязать сокеты к адресам"?

Comment: Чтобы в сообщении стояли те ip-адреса, какие я укажу.

Comment: Если клиент цепляется с адреса 1.1.1.1, то какой смысл указывать в сообщении адрес 2.2.2.2?

Comment: Если у клиента несколько адресов, и надо отправить не с того, который по умолчанию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Клиентский сокет

```
String serverIp = "10.0.0.1";
int serverPort = 1234;
int clientPort = 1234;
InetAddress clientIp = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.100");
Socket socket = new Socket(serverIp, serverPort, clientIp, clientPort);
```

Серверный сокет

```
Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.1",  1234));
```

Comment: Благодарю. В этом случае при создании клиента необходимо, чтобы был создан сервер. Узнал, что можно с помощью DatagramSocket отправлять UDP-пакеты (DatagramPacket) без предварительной установки соединения.